# HTML Textbox not typing

Tags: html

I need help. My form in my page looks like below however when I click on the text box the cursor won't appear and I can't type

```
<form name="input" action="postblog.php?name=<?PHP echo ($_GET['name']); ?>" method="post">    
    Post: <input type="text" name="text2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>
```

Comment: Because there's not more code than just these few lines, which are working perfectly, I guess you have JavaScript on your site which blocks the user input. Please give us more code so we can spot the real error.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an error that's not being displayed on your screen because it's appearing inside the HTML tags. Make sure to check if `$_GET['name']` is set first:

```
<form name="input" action="postblog.php?name=<?php echo ($_GET && isset($_GET['name'])) ? $_GET['name'] : 'No_Name_Value_From_GET'; ?>" method="post">
  Post: <input type="text" name="text2" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In this instance, if `$_GET['name']` is not set, the value for `?name=` will be `No_Name_Value_From_GET` (but you can change it to whatever you want).

HTH... :)