# Can't type in textarea

Tags: html

I am having trouble with my form below, when the user clicks the textarea the cursor does not appear and nothing can be typed, why is this?

```
 <form name="addblog" action="postblog.php?name=Alex" method="post">
  Post: <textarea name="text2" cols="25" rows="2">
 </textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: it might have to do with this typo action="postblog.php?..needing a "

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wg9S7/ Seems fine to me.

Comment: Works for me. Did you disable the textarea somewhere else with Javascript maybe?

Comment: This appears to be a repost of this question asked just a few moments ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392182/html-textbox-not-typing